# How to remove folder path within zip file.I want only txt files in zip file

Tags: asp.net, sharpziplib

I am generating a zip file from the folder 
`D:\Nagaraj\Dotnet\Zipfile\Zipfile\Filebuild\Hi`. There are 2 txt files within the folder.

But problem is that within the zip file there is the path `D:\Nagaraj\Dotnet\Zipfile\Zipfile\Filebuild\Hi` and within *that* folder are the 2 txt files.

Now I need to remove the path `D:\Nagaraj\Dotnet\Zipfile\Zipfile\Filebuild\Hi` and directly generate the `Hi.zip` with the 2 txt file in the root of the archive. I'm using SharpZipLib for creating the archive.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartZip("D:/Nagaraj/Dotnet/Zipfile/Zipfile/Filebuild/Hi",".zip");        
}

public void StartZip(string directory, string zipFileName)
{
    ZipFile z = ZipFile.Create(directory + zipFileName);
    z.BeginUpdate();
    string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
    foreach (string filename in filenames)
    {
        z.Add(filename);
    }
    z.CommitUpdate();
    z.Close();
}
```

Comment: What zip library are you using?

Comment: i am using sharpziplib library

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks to be how your creating the zip file. Your passing in the directory where the files are located in your call to `Add`.

Instead, just pass the file names using the [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) method:

```
public void StartZip(string directory, string zipFileName)
{
    ZipFile z = ZipFile.Create(directory + zipFileName);
    z.BeginUpdate();

    string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

    foreach (string filename in filenames)
    {
        z.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
    }
    z.CommitUpdate();
    z.Close();
}
```

Comment: I am used the  above coding ..the problem is..I can't find out where the zip file in created or whether created or not

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, but I don't think I understand your comment. Do you mean that after creating the zip file, you do not know where that zip has been created on the disk?

Comment: ya.....I find out which path it's created .This is created in this path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE" ....but problem is .I am trying to open that file .....it will show error "damaged data"

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Sharpziplib` but I would recommend looking at their documentation to see if there is a configuration option for the folder where the zip file will be created.